# how to convert NSString to NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a NSString(e.g. 'P1') 
I have to add 1 in this NSString to get 'P2'.
How will i do this??
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert **your** `NSString` to an `NSInteger` like so:

```
NSInteger myInteger = [[myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)] integerValue];
```

In your case if `myString` was your string P1, `myInteger` would be 1. So you could then do:

```
myInteger = myInteger + 1;
```

Which would then make `myInteger` 2. To then put that number back after P do:

```
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"P%i", myInteger];
```

Now `myString` is P2.

Answer (score 4):

Split it in to a prefix containing the P and a suffix containing the number.  How you do this depends on the possible format of your  string.

Then send intValue to the string.

Increment the number

Put it all back together with -stringWithFormat:

Comment: For the problem above, I think this would be the best and fastest solution. +1

Comment: If you want some code, see my answer, which does exactly what Jeremy states.